# working principle of Support Vector Machine

Tags: classification, svm, categorical-data

I have a dataset consisting of numerical features and categorical features. I want train the training set using SVM. SVM is a quadratic optimization algorithm. I would like to know the how SVM works on categorical data. Can anyone share any references, links to research papers, or weblink to describe the process?

I am also looking forward to know the theory behind handling categorical data using SVM.

Comment: See chapter 12 of [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand an algorithm very well, I use to study thoroughly the original paper, to understand the original mindset in creating it and the mathematical logic.

http://image.diku.dk/imagecanon/material/cortes_vapnik95.pdf

In parallel, I play with interactive demonstrators to check different use cases and test the limits.

For instance:

https://jgreitemann.github.io/svm-demo

[https://cs.stanford.edu/~karpathy/svmjs/demo/](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Ekarpathy/svmjs/demo/)

https://dash.gallery/dash-svm/